# Clojure (javadoc) function tries to load docs in a JFrame instead of web browser

Tags: clojure

As you see in title. Google cannot help because only pages I found was about setting java plugin in browser.

Clojure 1.5.1 started with 'lein repl' on Debian Wheezy. Oracle JDK installed with 'java-package' script.

EDIT: Looks like java.awt.Desktop/isDesktopSupported always returns false on Debian. It's an Oracle JRE bug/feature.

Comment: Which Clojure version you have? Do you use Lein?

Comment: Clojure 1.5.1 started with 'lein repl'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***javadoc*** tries to open the URL in browser or, when everything else fails, in a Swing browser.

You can have a look at [clojure.java.browse](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/be9ff491c4b2c23790fb316804551768960e355d/src/clj/clojure/java/browse.clj), particularly at [open-url-in-browser](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/be9ff491c4b2c23790fb316804551768960e355d/src/clj/clojure/java/browse.clj#L22):

> "Opens url (a string) in the default system web browser.  May not
>     work on all platforms.  Returns url on success, nil if not
>     supported."

But I'm not sure what is missing (or not working) on your Debian installation.

Comment: Looks like java.awt.Desktop/isDesktopSupported always returns false on Debian. It's an Oracle JRE bug/feature.